# Do not clear a split screen region when one command completes

Tags: gnu-screen

I run some commands in parallel and I want to see their last output after all of them complete (in the scrollback of my terminal emulator). Here's my test script `test.screen`:

```
# 
screen -t A sh -c 'echo important info && sleep 2'

split
focus

# 
screen -t B sh -c 'echo another important info && sleep 5'
```

The launch command:

```
$ screen -c test.screen
```

Output:

```
[screen is terminating]
[il@reallin ~]$


  --
another important info





   1 B
```

One problem is: when the first `sleep 2` completes, the printed message `important info` is erased. If I add `zombie kr` at the beginning, then screen does not exit at all. As a workaround the caller can wait for all screen processes to exit and then issue `-X quit`

The other problem: the caret does not move to the bottom when `screen` exits and the shell prompt overwrites some data. The workaround is to `echo` $LINES times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no good solution for a split screen region being cleared: zombie windows prevent screen from exiting. I had to add additional synchronization between the windows and the caller script and when they all die, I call `screen -X quit` explicitly.

The `altscreen` command had nothing to do with this. The cursor didn't move to the bottom, because my default `/etc/screenrc` was half-working: the host terminal altscreen feature was used, but the altscreen wasn't cleared before switching back. To make it work by default I copied `/etc/screenrc` from `CentOS 7` and for my case I disabled the feature completely with `termcapinfo * ti=:te=`.

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set -e

if [ "a" = "$1" ]; then
    # decrement file name towards zero, then kill screen
    set -e
    a=-1
    cd "$COUNTERDIR"

    while true; do
        for old in *; do
            new=$((old + a))
        done
        [ 0 -eq "$a" ] || 2>/dev/null mv ./$old ./$new && break
    done

    if [ 0 -eq "$new" ]; then
        screen -X quit
    fi
    exit
fi


NWINDOWS=2
COUNTERDIR=`mktemp -d`
touch "$COUNTERDIR/$NWINDOWS"

export COUNTERDIR

screen -c test.screen
rm -rf "$COUNTERDIR"
```

test.screen:

```
# do not use host terminal altscreen feature
termcapinfo * ti=:te=
# windows stay after command terminates
zombie kr

screen -t A sh -c 'for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do echo important info $i; done && sleep 5; ./test.sh a'

split
focus

screen -t B sh -c 'for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do echo another important info $i; done && sleep 2; ./test.sh a'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the screen to clear when exiting "screen", you should choose (or modify) a terminal description which does not switch to the alternate screen.  That is the `TERM` value *outside* `screen`.

With xterm (and a few others such as PuTTY) you can configure the terminal to prevent using the alternate screen, but for most terminals which copy xterm's alternate screen feature, this is hard-coded, not configurable.  So the terminal description is the place to start.

ncurses provides a terminal description "xterm1" which has the alternate screen suppressed (and seeing that it is in Debian, it's probably in derived distributions such as Ubuntu).  For other systems, it depends.  Here's a difference from infocmp:

```
comparing xterm1 to xterm.                                                     
    comparing booleans.      
    comparing numbers.        
    comparing strings.          
        rmcup: NULL, '\E[?1049l'.       
        smcup: NULL, '\E[?1049h'.
```

The "screen" program also has its own variant of the alternate screen which is normally off:

```
   altscreen on|off
   If set to on, "alternate screen" support is enabled in  virtual  termi‐  
   nals, just like in xterm.  Initial setting is `off'.
```

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)

Comment: We're talking not about the altscreen feature of xterm and likes, but about clearing the screen's window.

Comment: They are not separable, because the clearing happens using the outer terminal description.  I pointed that out in the first sentence.

Comment: adding `altscreen off` at the beginning of the script does not prevent clearing that region of the screen

Comment: Sure: **clearing** the terminal on exit from `screen` is controlled by the outer terminal description.  Inside, `screen` simulates its own *alternate screen* feature.

Comment: I cannot use your answer