# zsh colors get messed up when exiting some programs or resizing window

Tags: zsh, colors, ncurses

I face this issue with some programs that take over the full terminal, like ncmpcpp, weechat, cava, pipes.sh, and nvtop. If I resize the window after loading these programs, the color scheme changes to something that looks like gruvbox. Here's a screenshot with nvtop (the top is before resizing and the bottom is after resizing):
[image: nvtop before and after resizing]

Weechat turns into the gruvbox color scheme immediately on starting it, but if I reload the window manager, it fixes itself. When I enter cava or pipes.sh, it loads in the normal colorscheme, and when I resize the window it becomes gruvbox, just like the other programs I mentioned, but when I exit cava or pipes.sh, the background of the terminal becomes black regardless of whether I'd resized it or not. Here's a screenshot (top is after exiting nvtop without resizing, bottom left is after exiting nvtop after resizing, and bottom right is exiting cava without resizing):
[image: after exiting cava]
Note the color of the arrow in all three windows, and how the cava command is gone in the bottom right one. To be clear, my issue is not with the command going away, but the color scheme changing.

Running `. ~/.zshrc` after exiting these programs returns the color scheme.

#### Information that might be helpful:

- I'm using bspwm as my WM
- The terminal is alacritty
- The shell is zsh, and I have oh-my-zsh installed
- I use pywal for the colorscheme

I can provide my config files and other information if necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not clear a split screen region when one command completes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398093/do-not-clear-a-split-screen-region-when-one-command-completes)

Comment: @ThomasDickey no, I don't mind the screen clearing and that's not the main issue here. The issue is how the color scheme changes

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a different terminal than Alacritty?

Comment: @MarlonRichert yes, I just tried it in kitty and the issue persists.

Comment: Start a clean sub shell by doing `cd "$(mktemp -d)"; ZDOTDIR=$PWD HOME=$PWD zsh -df`. Try if you still have the same problem there. If not, the problem somewhere in your config. In that case, in the same sub shell, paste and run one by one the lines from your `.zshrc` until you find what combination of config causes your problem. Then update your question with it. Otherwise, it's impossible to investigate this. And if it turns out that the problem _does_ occur in the clean sub shell, then congratulations: You've found a bug. Go and report it. 

Comment: @MarlonRichert yes, the issue persists in the clean sub shell. What is this a bug in, though?

Comment: Given a clean subshell, what is the minimum set of steps you can take reproduce this?

Comment: @MarlonRichert I start the program (eg. ncmpcpp), then I resize the window. Done.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, but I'm on macOS. Have you tried using a different window manager? What if you don't use pywal for the color scheme?

Comment: @MarlonRichert no, I haven't tried it on a different window manager. But I just tried it in bash and the issue is not there.

Comment: Minor contribution: I am experiencing the same issue with nvtop running in zsh. I am *not* using pywal and I am using Gnome as DE and Tilix terminal.